# Codename One Error on send Android build

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

Am able to send my Android build but am getting this error on build server. What could be the problem?

```
Error encountered while parsing the class StateMachine$23.classException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 33446)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change an old project to Java 8?

If so make sure to define the build hint `java.version=8`.